# web scraping using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to **scrape** a site.

**Code:**

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    my_url = 'https://www.bewakoof.com/biker-t-shirts'
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    
    
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "productGrid"})
    
    print(len(containers))
```

I am getting below mentioned error.

**Error**

```py
o = containerClass(current_data)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: try getting the page with 'request' as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841271/web-scraping-with-python-and-beautiful-soup

Comment: If your error is from the line `o = containerClass(current_data)` then show us the definition of `containerClass` and post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

When I tryed to run part of yours code I've catch an error:

[image]

After that i've try to use requests:

```
>>> my_url = 'https://www.bewakoof.com/biker-t-shirts'
>>> import requests as re
>>> r = re.get(my_url)
>>> r
<Response [403]>
```

You have got code 403 - it means that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. You can get more information about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Most often, this error is associated with primitive protection from parsers. To solve this, use this method: You must use headers to `deceive` the site that you are a browser
 To do this download [requests lib](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
then create a dict

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
```

Instead of these values you can substitute your own. The easiest way to do this is with Network Analiser in your browser (press F12 in Chrome)
[image]

Then

```
import requests as req
url = "url"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
r = req.get(url, headers)
```

But in this situation, the problem is different. The site you are trying to access simply does not work:
[image]